# Which comes first, PDO::rollBack or __destruct

Tags: php, oop, pdo, transactions, destructor

When you run `PDO::beginTransaction`, if for any reason the script ends and the changes haven't been explicitly committed (on error, exception, `exit`/`die`, etc), the transaction will be rolled back.

Similarly, when the script ends, any `__destruct` methods present in any objects will likewise be executed.

So my question is, if the script ends and there is an outstanding database transaction, which gets called first, `PDO::rollBack` or the `__destruct` methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a PHP script ends and there is an outstanding PDO transaction, `PDO::rollBack` isn't called by PHP at all, but instead any remaining transactions are rolled back by the database server itself as soon as PHP closes the connection to the server, which happens after any [destructors](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor) or [shutdown functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) are executed.

Therefore, if we have the following:

```
$dbh = get_dbh();

class Test
{
    public function __construct(PDO $dbh)
    {
        $this->_dbh = $dbh;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $stmt = $this->_dbh->prepare("
            UPDATE some_table
            SET some_column = :val");
        $stmt->bindValue('val', time());
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}

$test = new Test($dbh);

$dbh->beginTransaction();

// End of file
```

The query in the `__destruct` method will be executed and then immediately rolled back.

Comment: It was surprisingly difficult using google to find an explicit statement saying that if PHP exits while there is a transaction in progress, changes are rolled back just as if $dbh->rollback() had been called. I guess this is because I was searching in relation to PHP and PDO, while it's actually a property of the database, when the connection on which the transaction was started is closed!